# Eclipse new Project only for file system, don't import into workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, rcp, pde

I want to create new CDT C++ Project with Eclipse templates.
But the code is being integrated in an other Project.
So I don't want to have the project in my workspace.
I only want to have it in my file system.

Is it possible to create new projects without importing them into my workspace?
The templates are self developed cdt plug ins. Does someone know how to execute code after using the cdt template extension? That I can do a workaround and delete it instantly from my workspace?

I would really appreciate your help!

Thank you!

Comment: You can delete a project from your workspace without deleting it from the filesystem. Does that help?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "execute code after invoking the extension".

Comment: @HighCommander4 Thanks for your answer, I have the code to programmaticly delete the project only from my workspace. But I don't know how I can tell Eclipse to execute my code after creating the new project. I want to say that I don't really know where to put my code that Eclipse knows to call it after creating my project.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand your question now. I don't know the answer though. Perhaps try the [CDT mailing list](https://accounts.eclipse.org/mailing-list/cdt-dev)?